# Unable to load asset bundles from streaming assets folder in Gameroom build

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-gameroom

We've just updated Unity to 5.5.1+

And game builds from this version can't load assets from local path in Gameroom build. We are loading assets via `UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle(url, version, crc)` where `url` - is absolute path.

In Unity 5.5.0f3 it works, but on 5.5.1+ it doesn't.

Facebook Gameroom uses functionality Chromium browser to cache assets. Looks like Unity has changed `UnityWebRequest` caching system.

How can we fix it?

Temporary workaround is to use `AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync`, but it's slower because streaming assets folder is compressed, so it will be decompress assets every in launch.